# How do I get X-Csrftoken from cookies that were sent using the server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, token, mobx

I am a novice developer of React/typescript. I use axios and mobx in my project. You need to do authorization. The main problem is that I can't get the expected csrftoken. Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code

**http.ts**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const API_URL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL;

const $api = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: API_URL,
    xsrfHeaderName: "X-CSRFToken",
    xsrfCookieName: "csrftoken",
})

export default $api;
```

**store.ts**

```
export default class Store {
    async sendCode(email: string) {
        try {
            const response = await AuthService.sendCode(email);
            console.log(response);
            sessionStorage.setItem('email', response.data.email);
            this.setAuth(false);
            this.setUser(response.data.user);
        } catch (e: any) {
            console.log(e.response?.data?.message);
        }
    }
```

**AuthService.ts**

```
export default class AuthService {
    static async sendCode(email: string): Promise<AxiosResponse<AuthResponse>> {
        return $api(
            {
                method: 'post',
                url: '/auth/login/',
                data: email,
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRFToken': document.cookie.split('=')[1],
                    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

Error 403 occurs (incorrect token). At the moment, I can't even see the token in the browser cookies in the client itself, although there are Cookies in the response headers
[No Cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPnUy.png)

I thought there was a bug in django. But the backender said that everything is fine and he has everything set up. I have the backender code, but I don't understand it very well.

Comment: Do I understand correctly? The CSRF Token should be in a cookie, but the cookie is not present? There is no way to access data from a cookie which isn't there. So you should solve that first.

Comment: This is the question of how I can get a token from the cookie that was sent from the server?

Comment: In my request headers there is a Cookie header Where the desired token is specified, but it is not displayed in the browser cookies